# Passing array pointer in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have a VHDL entity that defines a block RAM as an array:

```
type BYTE_RAM_TYPE is array (0 to 255) of std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
signal ram                            : BYTE_RAM_TYPE;
```

I have another VHDL entity that was generated by Vivado HLS tools. It converts a C function with prototype:

```
void dividedBy2(int array0Input[10], const int numElements);
```

to VDHL entity:

```
entity dividedBy2 is
port (
    ap_clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
    ap_rst : IN STD_LOGIC;
    ap_start : IN STD_LOGIC;
    ap_done : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    ap_idle : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    ap_ready : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    array0Input_address0 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    array0Input_ce0 : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    array0Input_we0 : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    array0Input_d0 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
    array0Input_q0 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
    numElements : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0) );
end;
```

I am not sure how to connect array0Input_q0 so that it uses the address of "signal ram".

I read somewhere that I can use the "access type", i.e.:

```
type BYTE_RAM_TYPE_ACCESS is access BYTE_RAM_TYPE
```

However, I would need to use "new" to dynamically allocate BYTE_RAM_TYPE. Is there another way to do this ?

Thank you very much with any help..

Comment: Objects of access types are not synthesis eligible, serving allocation and deallocation of storage during simulation. There is also no visible correlation between the HLS function divideBy2 and the entity divideBy2 which appears intended to operate a RAM. Note that BYTE_RAM_TYPE has an element with length 8 while array0Input_d0 and array0Input_q0 have a length 32 (they are not compatible). The structure of the entity appears to imply multiple independent accesses to a memory with a size based on numElements as shown in array0Input_address0. That also doesn't match. Instantiate a matching RAM.

Comment: This seems an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/xy-problem/info). HLS deals with abstraction (hiding complexity), that can't be done in VHDL. Generated code for implementing things abstractly described can be overly complex. Are you trying to patch HLS generated VHDL code, and for what purpose? An HLS generated implementation will never be as small or efficient as native VHDL. What isn't clear from the snippets you show is what divideBy2 does, how many read ports are necessary for RAM implementation of array0Input and whether a RAM is actually appropriate.

Comment: You are pondering how to code software.   Instead, you need to think about hardware.   Memory elements in hardware have a defined number of interfaces.   Unlike software, you cannot read a structure except through one of the interfaces.   Hence, you need to first visualize what the hardware is and what interfaces it has before you can consider how to code it.

Comment: Also with array based structures, be careful to look at what FPGA's memories have as required elements - such as mandatory flip-flop placement in the distributed vs block style RAMs.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the comments. We are not trying to patch the HLS generated HDL code. This is a test program that I developed to familiar myself with Xilinx development board. The ultimate goal of this test program is to use C code (running on PowerPC), to write some data to some block ram in FPGA, and then have FPGA does some processing to it, and the C code will read the result back from that memory). The BYTE_RAM_TYPE is auto-generated by Xilinx and I understand that I possibly need to change its configuration, like size of the RAM, and each element size.

Comment: Since our ultimate goal is to synthesize a rather complex algorithm, we were hoping to use HLS to generate the VHDL code. I understand that this is not the best way to go about this but we have very limited resources. What the dividedBy2 function does is basically going through the elements starting from array0Input to array0Input + numElements, and divide each element by 2. I chose this example cause this mimic the interface of our complex algorithm. So is there a way to know the address of the first element in BYTE_RAM_
TYPE ? Thanks again.